# populate contact images in my imageview using expandablelistview

Tags: java, android

**ChatFirstTab.java**

```
public class ChatFirstTab extends Fragment{

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
String name, photo;

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_first, container, false);

    expListView = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);

    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    return rootView;
}

private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
            null, null, null, null);

    int count = cursor.getCount();

    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        Log.d("name : ", name);
        listDataHeader.add(name);
    }

    cursor.close();

    // Adding child data
    List<String> request = new ArrayList<String>();
    request.add("Send Request");

    int i;

    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), request); // Header, Child data
    }
  }
}
```

**ExpandableListAdapter.java**

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_first_list_items, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_first_list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

My question is, I want to display **Contact images** for the particular person. Now the *contact name* is displaying correctly. I want contact image also to be displayed along name.

I have tried many method but nothing helped. Is there any method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get both contact name and image by using the below code..

```
private String getContact(String ph)
    {
        String contactName = null;
        try{
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                    PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                    Uri.encode(ph));
            ContentResolver cr=getActivity().getContentResolver();
            Cursor cursor1 = cr.query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,PhoneLookup.PHOTO_URI}, null, null, null);
            if (cursor1 == null) {
                return "";
            }

            if(cursor1.moveToFirst()) {
                contactName = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
                image_uri=cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.PHOTO_URI));
                cursor1.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return contactName;
    }
```

To display the images in the list i am using `UniversalImageLoader`.

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = null;
                            imageLoader =ImageLoader.getInstance();
                            if(image_uri!=null)
                            {

                                options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                                        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.profile)
                                        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.profile)
                                        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.profile)
                                        .cacheInMemory(true)
                                        .cacheOnDisc(true)
                                        .considerExifParams(true)
                                        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
                                        .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(200)).build();


                                imageLoader.displayImage(image_uri, img,options);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                imageLoader.displayImage("drawable://" +R.drawable.profile, img,options);
                            }
```

My Adapter class:

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {

        Context context;
        ImageLoader imageLoader = null;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context)
        {
            super(context,0);
            this.context=context;
            sectionIndices=getSectionIndices();
            sectionDates=getSectionDates();
            imageLoader =ImageLoader.getInstance();
            options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .considerExifParams(true)
                    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.profile)
                    .cacheInMemory(true)
                    .cacheOnDisc(true)
                    .considerExifParams(true)
                    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.profile)
                    .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.profile)
                    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
                    .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(200)).build();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            int size=0;
            try
            {
                size=db1.size();

            }
            catch(NullPointerException e)
            {

            }
            return size;
        }



        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
            if(convertView==null)
            {
                convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_log_screen, null);
            }
            final TextView tv= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView tv2=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            ImageView pic=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);



            RelativeLayout rel=(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);


            String name=getContact(db1.get(position).phone);
            if(name!=null)
            {
                tv.setText(name);
            }
            else
            {
                tv.setText(db1.get(position).phone);
            }


            if(photoUri.get(position)!=null)
            {
                imageLoader.displayImage(photoUri.get(position), pic,options);
            }
            else
            {
                imageLoader.displayImage("drawable://" +R.drawable.profile, pic, options);
            }



            return convertView;
        }





    }
```

Comment: how to pass image variable to my adapter?

Comment: I have attached my adapter class .. Please check :)

Comment: You want to display the image in the groupView or childview of ExpandableListView?

Comment: I want to display image in `groupView ` of `ExpandableListView`

Comment: You can do it in two ways  1. You can store both the contact name and the image in a map and get both name and image in getGroupView method and display both.       2. You can get the image uri  by calling the method inside getGroupView methed using contact name or number and set the image there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81596/discussion-between-jithin-varghese-and-anusha-bh).